# jQuery - как анимировать width

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div style="width:70%">
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как используя JQuery, в течение 2 секунд увеличить объект до 100%?

**1%** = **66.6666666667 миллисекунд**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте `jQuery.animate`

Например:
`$('.first').animate({'width':'100%'},2000)`